# CSV into MySQL Database

Tags: java, mysql

i have the following snippet:

```
    String insertSql =  "LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:/thomsonReuters/compressed/premium-world-check-day.csv'"
                    + " INTO TABLE thomsenreuters.worldcheck " 
                    + " FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' " 
                    + " ENCLOSED BY '\"' " 
                    + " LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' " 
                    + " IGNORE 1 ROWS;";
```

This file has 4567 total rows. The fields are terminated by a tab and enclosed by double quotes. I try to insert the csv file by a Prepared-Update stmt. But Java only insert the first 4 rows into MySQL. What is the misstake i've done?

Thanks for help

**EDIT**

**Full Class Code:**

```
Connection con = null;
    PreparedStatement stmt = null;

    String truncateTable = "Truncate table thomsenreuters.worldcheck;";

    String insertSql =  "LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:/thomsonReuters/compressed/premium-world-check-day.csv'"
                    + " INTO TABLE thomsenreuters.worldcheck " 
                    + " FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' " 
                    + " ENCLOSED BY '\"' " 
                    + " LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' " 
                    + " IGNORE 1 ROWS;";    

    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {            
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println("Driver was found");

    try {
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/thomsenreuters","XXXXXXX","XXXXXXX");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("Connection to Database");

    System.out.println("Start insert...");
    try {
        con.setAutoCommit(false);
        stmt = con.prepareStatement(truncateTable);
        stmt = con.prepareStatement(insertSql);         
        int total  = stmt.executeUpdate();
        con.commit();
        con.setAutoCommit(true);

        System.out.println("Total Rows insert " + total);



    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally{
        if(stmt != null)
        {
            try {
                stmt.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if(con != null)
        {
            try {
                con.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {                  
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: provide first 5 rows of data

Comment: Does it work when you execute same query on mysql command line? If not, then I think there are some invalid characters in your CSV file.

Comment: To improve your program error reporting you should print the whole `SQLException` chain (if any exception is thrown) and also the full list of `SQLWarning` in the connection

Comment: If i execute the same query in mysql than i got the error code : 1261 Row 4 doesn't contain data for all columns. So what must i change? Each row has an entry, but not in all columns.

Comment: I got it. The error was that i must change ENCLOSED BY '\"' TO ENCLOSED BY ' '.